# iOS 8.3 & 8.4 Emoji gets disappeared

Tags: ios, keyboard, emoji

I have a sample chat app but emoji keyboard showing no emoji sometimes & this issue occurs only in iOS 8.3.x to iOS 8.4.x, everything works fine in iOS 9 & above.

Screenshot attached for reference:

[image: Emoji Disappeared]

Did anyone faced any similar issue in past or has any solution related to this?